# How to change timeout in JDI Test Automation Framework

Tags: jdiframework

I need to change timeout for waiting particular webElements. For all of others default is pretty fine. Default timeout could be changed in settings:

```
timeout.wait.element=10
```

How to change timeout only for given elements?

Answer (score 0):

For setting specific timeout on element you can use

textField.setWaitTimeout(10);

textField.input("TEXT");

But if you also has some waiting criteria and want to do something after it becomes true you can use

String text = textField.wait(w -> w.getText(), t -> t.equals("test"), 10);

or textField.wait(w -> w.getText().equals("test"), 10); if you just want to wait something

Answer (score 0):

For setting specific implicit timeout on element you can use @WaitTimeout(sec)
@WaitTimeout(sec) — set sec seconds implicit wait for the element

or if you just want to wait until element is present in DOM:
someWebElement.waitFor(10).displayed();